# Gradle - SIngle with Multiple Jars into Maven Repository

Tags: maven, gradle

I have a Gradle project which when build creates multiple Jar files based on certain rules like Classes A,B and C goto A.jar, Classes D,E and F goto B.jar and so on.

Now I want to upload these Jar files into Maven repository. Though I am able to do it but I want to put each of these Jars in Maven Repository as a standalone artifact.

For ex: Right now if I have project named MyProject and it has produces 2 Jar files : A.jar and B.jar, then in maven repository i have following structure

```
-------   Repo
          |
          |----com
               |
               |--- project
                    |
                    |---- MyProject
                          |
                          |---- version 1
                            | 
                            |--- A.jar
                            |--- B.jar
```

But i want the following structure

```
-------   Repo
          |
          |----com
               |
               |--- project
                    |
                    |---- MyProject
                          |
                          |---- A
                            | 
                            |--- Version 1
                              |
                              |--- A.jar
                            |---- B 
                            |
                            |---- Version 1
                               |
                               |--- B.jar
```

That means i want to make sure that both A.jar and B.jar are two different artifacts in Maven repository, so that I can maintain different version of two.

Right now, In order to put both the jars in maven repository I made sure I add following piece of code in build.gradle.

```
artifacts {
  archives A,B    
}
```

One solution would be to have two different Gradle Projects containing the relevant classes and each project producing its own artefact but in my case this can't be short term solution. we already have something like this planned but that has low priority.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all documented in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html). See [Multiple artifacts per project](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html#sub%3amultiple_artifacts_per_project) if you are using the "maven" plugin, and [Publishing multiple modules](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven%3apublish-multiple-publications) if you are using the "maven-publish" plugin.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mentioned I am using gradle version 0.9.2 and correct me if I am wrong maven-publish is not available in that version.

Comment: That's why I also provided a link for the "maven" plugin. Best check it out in the 0.9.2 docs: http://www.gradle.org/docs/0.9.2/userguide/maven_plugin.html#sub%3amultiple_artifacts_per_project You should really upgrade though.

Comment: I am already using that but not sure how that can help in creating the structure i mentioned. I suppose it explains all about how will you upload multiple artifacts and mentions which one.

Comment: If you follow "Generation of multiple poms", you should get exactly the structure you mentioned.